# Show that $ h \in C^n(\mathbb{R}^2)$ where $h(u,v) = u^2v - 4 + (v-1)e^{u-2}$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

As the title says I have to show that $ h \in C^n(\mathbb{R}^2)$, but I do not know how to show it.

I know that the partial derivatives of h have to exist and be continous in order for h to be $C^n$, but how do I show this?

Do I start out with $n=1$ and then move on until I see a pattern?

Comment: hint: sum and product of smooth functions are smooth again.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know how to use this hint. Do I have to look at the partial derivatives? Or?

Comment: Is it because all of the partial derivatives of h are sums and products of smooth functions?

Comment: you know that differentiation is linear and the product rule. now, for example, $(u,v) \mapsto u^2$ is smooth. do you other smooth functions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint. Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are two functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$; define $h \colon \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $h(u,v)=f(u)g(v)$. Convince yourself that if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, then so is $h$. Now iterate $n$ times.

To apply this to your case, remark that your map can be decomposed into the sum of three functions of the previous form.